# Powershell Array Strings - Mapping different variable parameter name in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis, bamboo

I'm automating an SSIS Deployment. And I want to Map the parameters the parameters from environment. The parameters from package and environment have different variable name. Example is below

```
 $ParameterCount = 2          # Value will be coming from environment variable that is set
 $vPackage1 = "vId"           # Value will be coming from environment variable 
 $vEnvironment1 = "ApiId"     # Value will be coming from environment variable
 $vPackage2 = "vKey"          # Value will be coming from environment variable
 $vEnvironment2 = "ApiKey"    # Value will be coming from environment variable

 $vPackage = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
 $vEnvironment= [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

 for ($i = 1; $i -le $(ParamterCount); $i += 1) {
      # This doesnt work!!!. I want to get the value of vPackage1 variable
      $vPackage[$i].Add($vPackage + $i)      

      # This doesnt work!!!. I want to get the value of vPackage2 variable
      $vEnvironment[$i].Add($vPackage + $i)         
 }

 # Then for deployment. I want to Map those two variables.
 $Counter = $Counter + 1
 $Package.Paramters[$vPackage[$Counter]]
     .Set([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.ParameterInfo
     + ParameterValueType]::Referenced, $vEnvironment[$Counter])
```

I'm going to use Bamboo for Deployment. And the variables stated above is coming from the variables from Bamboo.

How can i handle this?

Comment: There are multiple coding errors in your script such as a $ sign before the actual For loop, making it a variable, not a loop. Please refractor every possible compiling error and update, as it is way too time-intensive, to fix them. Thanks.

Comment: You have typo's in there `ParamterCount`. Not only that, but your loop is wrong: `$for ($i = 1; $i -le $(ParamterCount); $i += 1) {` should be `for ($i = 1; $i -le $ParameterCount; $i++) {`. Next this makes no sense at all: `$vPackage[$i].Add($vPackage + $i)`.. You are adding the Arraylist `$vPackage` to the arraylist itself (and try to add an integer value of 1 to it)???. Also `$Counter = Counter + 1` without the dollar sign, and the list goes on..

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to get the variable's output of $vPackage1 which is I only added $vPackage + $i to demonstrate my question. @Theo

Comment: `$vPackage + $i` does NOT get you the name or value of variable `$vPackage1`. To get the value for a variable with a constructed name, use `(Get-Variable -Name ('vPackage' + $i)).Value`. Next, you will hit another exception by using `$vPackage[$i].Add`. Adding to an Arraylist is on the list itself, NOT on an indexed item (which btw has not yet been created), so you should use `[void]$vPackage.Add` there. (the `[void]` is there to suppress the output you get from the `Add` method. And, as said, on to the next errors: breaking code with newlines at random places, typos ...

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is that I created a script to map variables from CSV file. And save first column from array, the same as the second column save from array. Then map the package and environment variables.